# If I mix 1 unit of water at at 30C° with 1 unit of water at 60C°, is the resulting water at 45C°?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, water

I'm curious how temperatures work when mixing water. I'm not very good at physics but I'm always learning.

Let's say I've 1 gallon of water at 30C° and 1 gallon of water at 60C°, and I mix them together. What is the final temperature of mixed water? Is it the average? Intuitively I'd say it's average but I don't know physics laws exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When two quantities of water ($m_1$ and $m_2$) at different temperatures (resp. $T_1$ and $T_2$) are mixed in *adiabatic conditions* (no heat loss and no external heating during mixing) the temperature $T$ of the resulting mixture can be calculated from the heat balance (no heat is lost or added so the heat contained in both masses is found again in the mixture):

$$m_1c_wT_1+m_2c_wT_2=(m_1+m_2)c_wT,$$

where $c_w$ is the Specific Heat Capacity of water.

Since as here $m_1=m_2$ and because $c_w$ drops out of the equation, we simply get:

$$T=\frac{T_1+T_2}{2}.$$

In your case of $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$, $T=45^\circ$.

**Edit:**

Following the comments, let's use the data [presented on this page](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-thermal-properties-d_162.html) to evaluate some corrections suggested.

Firstly, $1\:\mathrm{Gal}=4.546\:\mathrm{l}$ and with the densities listed for the relevant temperatures we have:

$m_1=4.526\:\mathrm{kg}$ and $m_2=4.469\:\mathrm{kg}$ and $m_1+m_2=8.995\:\mathrm{kg}$

The web page also provides values of $c_w$ at $30^\circ$ of $4.178\:\mathrm{kJ/kg^\circ C}$ and at $60^\circ$ of $4.185\:\mathrm{kJ/kg^\circ C}$.

Of course we strictly speaking we don't know $T$ and thus not $c_w$ at that temperature either. I'll assume that the influence of $T$ on $c_w$ between $30^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ is linear. Then we can determine that:

$$c_w(T)=4.171+0.000233T.$$

These data can now be inserted in the original equation:

$4.526 \times 4.178 \times 30 + 4.469 \times 4.185 \times 60 = 8.995 \times (4.171+0.000233T) \times T$

or:

$0.0021T^2+37.5T-1689.5=0$

Solving this quadratic equation the usual way we get:

$$\large{T=44.94^\circ}$$

So, barely $0.06^\circ$ difference with regards to the approximate solution. Well worth the approximation, in my opinion. While the comments are correct, a significant discrepancy between the simple and more refined model would only arise at much larger temperature differences, not a mere $30^\circ$ range.

Comment: Correct me, but I thought specific heat capacity is measured per mass. In your calculation you assumed that 45 °C and 60 °C warm water have the same density.

Comment: The heat capacity is also a function of temperature.

Comment: Although this answer is approximately correct there are some assumptions made which are not quite true: (i) (as Max Ried points out) it assumes constant density of water (i.e. one gallon of water at 30dc is the same mass as one gallon at 60dc), when in fact water at 60dc is about 1% less dense than water at 30dc; (ii) it assumes constant heat capacity of water, when in fact the heat capacity of water increases by about 0.2% between 30dc and 60dc.

Comment: See the data here, for example: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-thermal-properties-d_162.html

Comment: Wow... So complicated... I removed accepted answer for now so someone can do precise calculation. It's the same tap water heated, and the room temperature is °20C.

Comment: @MaxRied: of course this is a simplification. Do you think someone who states 'I'm not very good at physics' would be served well by a calculation that takes into account small density changes and the fact that $c_w$ is *very slightly* dependent on temperature in the interval used here? Most engineers would, for the example in question, use the approximations I used. The error introduced is very small.

Comment: Thank you very much. During these two days I learned a lot. I'm now slightly better at physics! Your answer is really great and taught a lot. I wouldn't have even thought about it without comments. I'm now much more educated. I'm accepting it again.